# MVC DropDownList set selected value and fill model property from user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I am using MVC and have a problem with drop downs.

I pass a model with Properties "Type" and "Visitor" in them i save selected values for drop downs.I have a functionality to write items in drop down from database and want drop down to read the value from model property and make it selected in the list, but when user change selected item to also change the property.

First dropdown fill the value in the model property on user select, but not read it from there (to set the item as selected).
Second drop down read value from model and set it as selected element, but when user make change do not rewrite property.

I want to have fill selected items functionality from first drop down, and model property write functionality from second.

Thank you in advice. This is the code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    @Html.DropDownList(Model.Type,
                 new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
                 {
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "DefaultValue", Value=""},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "Value1", Value="1"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "Value0", Value="0"}
                 }, "Value", "Text", Model.Type), new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">

    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Visitor,
                 new SelectList(new List<SelectListItem>
                 {
                     new SelectListItem {Text = "DefaultValue", Value=""},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "Value1", Value="1"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "Value0", Value="0"}
                 }, "Value", "Text", Model.Visitor), new { @class = "form-control" })

</div>
```

Comment: Impossible to understand what your trying to ask here. But there is no point creating an identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the 1st one (and setting the last parameter of `SelectList` does nothing at all when you bind to a property (its ignored) and you set the `null` label option using the 3rd parameter of `DropDownListFor()` - your code just needs to be `@Html.DropDownList(Model.Type, new List<SelectListItem>{ new SelectListItem {Text = "Value1", Value="1"}, new SelectListItem {Text = "Value0", Value="0"}, "DefaultValue", new { @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: And the code for generating the `SelectList` belongs in the controller, not the view.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript and wire-up to change event.